# wrapper background image won't disapear off page

Tags: html, css

I'm making a landing page that has a background header images of 1500.

the content container is 950px

I need it so the content stays in the center when the screen size changes ( not mobile just desktop )

At the moment when i resize the screen down below 1499 I get a scroll bar and nothing on page moves. 
What i'd like is for the content to move center and the background image to move off screen on either size evenly

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="content">
     <p>all copy etc </p>
 </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#wrapper{ width: 1500px; margin: 0 auto; background:url(images.jpg); background-repeat: no-repeat;   }
.content{width: 950px;  margin: 0 auto;  }
```

The wrapper image is 1500px width - But when the screen resizes i need some of that to go off page ( evenly ) so the content stays center to the background image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following styles - comments in code

```css
#wrapper {
  width: 100%;         /* make div 100% width with a max width so it will shrink below 1500px */
  max-width: 1500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: url(images.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position:top center;   /* make sure background is aligned to the top and center of the element */
}

.content {
  width: 100%;   /* make div 100% width with a max width so it will shrink below 1500px */
  max-width: 950px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="content">
    <p>all copy etc </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thats is exactly what i'm looking for . thank you worked perfect. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use overflow:hidden which will hide the extra overflow space.

Comment: I just tested that and it didn't work. didn't seem to have any effect